# hideSheet() being executed, but not actually hiding the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I am running this function i made in Google Apps Script for a spreadsheet add-on.  It does everything right, but every OTHER execution it doesn't hide the sheet. Any ideas?

```
function addEmailNew(formObject) {
  var newEmail = formObject.addEmailText;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("No Touching!").activate();

  //find the last string value in a column
  var Avals = ss.getRange("J:J").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length + 1;
  ss.getSheetByName('No Touching!').getRange("J" + Alast).setValue(newEmail);

  //THIS IS THE THING THAT WORKS EVERY OTHER TIME
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();

  openDialog();
  return Logger.log("this did stuff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to get the active sheet, but prior to hide it, activate another sheet. Try something like the following:

```
var sheetToHide = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getSheetByName("Other sheet").activate();
sheetToHide.hideSheet();
```

If the problem persists, add `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` on a new line after `hideSheet()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ruben.  Sadly neither activating another sheet nor putting in the flush method worked :(